# Android Webview crashes the app

Tags: java, android, webview

Implemented webview in my app. But when debugging, it gets crashed.

This is my MakePaymentActivity.java

```
public class MakePaymentActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public static String bookingId, userId, refId, Url;
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_payment);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        Url = URLConstants.MAKE_PAYMENT+"?user_id="+userId+"&ref_id="+refId+"&book_id="+bookingId;
        startWebView(Url);
    }

    private void startWebView(String url) {

        //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        //When opening a url or click on link

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MakePaymentActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try{
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }); 

         // Javascript inabled on webview  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }

}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/webview">
 </WebView>
```

Please help to solve this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the LogCat please.

Comment: Logcat is the best friend of Android developers!

Comment: When starting this activity, Logcat doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you add permission to your manifest?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Yes. I already integrate the google map in the app.

Comment: When the app crashes there really should be some logcat info. It's likely that you have a logcat filter set to filter out the needed info, or are otherwise not using logcat correctly. Without this primary data on what went wrong, we can't help much. You can also try making the debugger stop on exceptions.

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint in `onCreate()` then single-step through it to see what goes wrong. BTW your XML file here is missing the </LinearLayout> but that's probably just a copy/pasteo.

Comment: I got this in Debug window when i use breakpoint `Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 907 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 696`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I'm new to Android. I found the problem. i just forgot to declare the activity in AndroidManifest.xml